# Proving Basic Limit Property of CDFs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

> $\textbf{The Problem:}$ Let $F$ be the CDF of a random variable $X$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}F(t)=1.$

$\textbf{My Thoughts:}$ We claim that $\{X\leq n\}\nearrow\Omega\quad\text{as }n\to\infty.$ First we note that the set $\{X\leq n\}$ are nested nondecreasing, since $X\leq n$ implies that $X\leq n+1.$ 
Now, we clearly have $\bigcup_n\{X\leq n\}\subseteq\Omega$. Now let $\omega\in\Omega$ be arbitrary but fixed. Then $X(\omega)$ is a real number, so there exists an integer $m$ such that 
$X(\omega)<m$, and hence $\omega\in\{X\leq m\}$, so $\omega\in\bigcup_n\{X\leq n\}$, whence $\bigcup_n\{X\leq n\}=\Omega.$ Then the continuity of the probability measure implies that 
$F(n)=P(\{X\leq n\})\to P(\Omega)=1$ as $n\to\infty$. Now we are ready to tackle the problem.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given and choose $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $1-\varepsilon<F(n).$ Then by the monotonicity of the CDF, we have that $t\geq n$ implies that $1-\varepsilon<F(n)\leq F(t)\leq1,$ so that 
$\vert F(t)-1\vert<\varepsilon.$ This proves that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}F(t)=1.$

---

Do you agree with the above proof? Any feedback is much appreciated. Thank you for your time and have a great week.

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Comment: Your proof looks right. The key idea is continuity from below. It can be noted that CFB holds for all measures (not just probabilities)

Comment: Im bothered by your  phrase "Then the continuity of the probability measure implies...". You are not, I hope, assuming $F$ is a continuous function?

Comment: @kimchilover By continuity of the probability measure I mean the following: Let $A_1,\dots\in\Omega$ be such that $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$, then we set $A=\bigcup_n A_n$. We write $A_n\nearrow A$. Then it follows that $P(A_n)\to P(A)$ as $n\to\infty$. Apologies for any lack of clarity.

Comment: I agree, your argument is correct.  "Continuity" means different things, and if I were less sleepy it would have been clear to me which kind you were talking about.